# Estimating parameters using minimization in Python and speed up this process

Tags: python-3.x, minimization

I am trying to find parameter estimates using using minimization. The code I wrote works but there are two problems:

1. I finds only a local minimum. I tried to solve this by using basinhopping.
2. It takes very long until I get a result and since I have to do this minimization around 1000 times this becomes a big issue.

So my questions are:

1. Do you know how I could optimize my code so that it runs faster for the minimization.
2. Is there a way I can change the basinhopping part so that it runs faster? eg. set niter lower or a differnt method im not aware of. I tried running it like this and after 10 hour I didnt get a response for even one of the 1000 individuals for basinhopping.
3. Is there another way to find a global minimum?

Feel free to ask further questions please.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pickle
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy.random as npr
import csv


path = "C:\\Users\Sebastian Gäumann\OneDrive\Dokumente\FS 2017\Bachelorarbeit\Python"
os.chdir(path)
###IDS
df = pd.read_csv('1_Youtuber_SingleNrSheet_Comedy.csv', sep = ";", skipinitialspace=True)                                                    ######Change Name
YoutuberID = df["Channel_ID"].tolist()


##print(YoutuberID)



with open("9_p_q_m_Fun_ExtendedBass_VIEWS_Comedy_test.csv", "w" ,newline='',encoding='utf-8') as csv_file2:                                                        ######Change Name
    csv_writer2 = csv.writer(csv_file2, delimiter=';')

    csv_writer2.writerow(["Type","p", "q", "m","Functionvalue"])



    count = 0    
    for ID in YoutuberID[0:]:                                                                                                                      ###Change

        try:

            path = "C:\\Users\Sebastian Gäumann\OneDrive\Dokumente\FS 2017\Bachelorarbeit\Python"
            os.chdir(path)

            ###ALL INFO
            Days = pd.read_csv('3_API_Call_ALL_info_Comedy_v2.csv', sep = ";", skipinitialspace=True)

            views_path = "C:\\Users\Sebastian Gäumann\OneDrive\Dokumente\FS 2017\Bachelorarbeit\Python\Daily_Views_Comedy"                                               ######Change Name
            os.chdir(views_path)

            SVR = pd.read_csv("4_COMEDY_DailyViews_Clean_" + str(count) + "_" + ID + ".csv", sep = ";", parse_dates=True,  dayfirst=True)  ######Change Name

##            print(SVR[SVR.columns[0]])

            SVR = SVR[SVR[SVR.columns[0]]< "2018-05-01"]                                                       ####CHANGE DATE FOR DIF CAT
##            print(SVR)

            #####SV Input
            SV = np.array(SVR["Daily Views"])


##            print(SV)
            Days = Days[Days["channelId"] == ID]

##            print(Days)

            Days["publishedAt"] = pd.to_datetime(Days.publishedAt)

            Days = Days[Days["publishedAt"] > "2015-01-08"] ##"2015-01-10"


##            print(Days)

            ##### Timedelta #####

            start_date = pd.to_datetime("2015-06-08")
            ##print(start_date)

            video_upload_day =[]

            for video_date in Days["publishedAt"]:
                TimeDelta = video_date - start_date
                video_upload_day.append(TimeDelta.days)

            ##print(video_upload_day)
            ##print(videoT)

            nvideos = len(video_upload_day)
            ndays = len(SV)


            videoT = np.array(video_upload_day)

##            print(videoT,nvideos,ndays)



            def objective(x):
                p = x[0] 
                q = x[1]
                m = x[2]


                estimateV = np.zeros( (ndays, nvideos) )

                for t in range( ndays ):
                    for v in range( nvideos ):
                                if videoT[v] <= t:
                                     estimateV[ t,v ] = p*m  +  (q-p) * np.sum(estimateV[0:t,v],axis=0)  -   (q/m) * (np.sum(estimateV[0:t,v],axis=0)**2)

                estimateSV = np.sum( estimateV, axis = 1 )


                return np.sum( (SV - estimateSV)**2 )
```

This is the minimization part. I made one for the normal minimization and one for basinhopping and seperated it with ##.

```
            ###### MINIMIZATION #######

            mguess = round(sum(SV)/(nvideos*2),0)

            print(sum(SV),mguess)

            x0 = np.array([0.001, 0.01, mguess])   ####Make it less volatile to first guess? Make bigger steps for m?

            b1 = (0.00001,0.5)
            b2 = (10**4,10**7)              
            bnds = (b1,b1,b2)


##            minimizer_kwargs = dict(method="L-BFGS-B",bounds=bnds)
##            res = basinhopping(objective, x0,niter=20, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)

            res = minimize(objective, x0,bounds = bnds)
            print(res)

            csv_writer2.writerow(["COMEDY",res.x[0], res.x[1],res.x[2],res.fun])                     ###CHANNGE CAT

            print("CURRERNT YOUTUBER IS:",count)
            count += 1

        except:

            print("PROBLEM",count)
            count += 1
    ##        print(res,res.x[0],res.x[1],res.x[2],res.fun)
```